# Append to string in existing associative array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to append to an existing string inside an associative array.

I know this works:

```
$a = ['key' => 'value'];
$a['key'] = $a['key'] . ' appended';
```

But am wondering of other options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option

```
$a = ['key' => 'value'];
$a['key'] .= ' appended';
```

Another option

```
$a['key'] = sprintf('%s %s' , $a['key'], 'appended');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am of the opinion that you cannot do that in php.

**You can't append/extend values to an existing array value in php!**

All solutions are only an overwrite/replace of an existing value in an array.

Check this in **php.net**
[Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)